# How do I add/enable memberOf attribute in Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition

Tags: oracle, ldap, directory-server

I confirm that `MemberOf Plugin` is enabled in the Oracle Directory Server, `memberOf` attribute is in Standard Attributes list in Schema: Attributes. In the detail of memberOf attribute, there are three entries in `Used as Allowed by` list: `inetAdmin`, `inetUser`, `nsManagedPerson`.

But all of user accounts do not belong to them. Instead, they have ObjectClass: `inetOrgPerson`, `organizationalPerson`, `person`, `top`. And it seems that I cannot add additional ObjectClass to the user.

How can I enable or add memberOf attribute to existing user account? And how can it auto populates the group name or DN to all of the user account?

Answer (score 3):

As ixe013 pointed out, ODSEE names their attribute "isMemberOf" instead of "memberOf". On OpenLDAP, your search would look like the following:

```
ldapsearch -x -w password -D "uid=abergin,ou=People,dc=odsee-qa,dc=qa,dc=abc,dc=com" -b "uid=abergin,ou=People,dc=odsee-qa,dc=qa,dc=abc,dc=com" '(objectclass=*)' "memberOf"
```

For ODSEE, you would use the following:

```
ldapsearch -x -w password -D "uid=abergin,ou=People,dc=odsee-qa,dc=qa,dc=abc,dc=com" -b "uid=abergin,ou=People,dc=odsee-qa,dc=qa,dc=abc,dc=com" '(objectclass=*)' "isMemberOf"
```

Which returns something like the following:

```
version: 1
dn: uid=abergin, ou=People, dc=odsee-qa,dc=qa,dc=abc,dc=com
isMemberOf: cn=QA Managers,ou=groups,dc=odsee-qa,dc=qa,dc=abc,dc=com
isMemberOf: cn=Accounting Managers,ou=groups,dc=odsee-qa,dc=qa,dc=abc,dc=com
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not use the legacy DSEE any more, but if I recall correctly, the `memberOf` attribute is generated by the directory server based on group membership, not added to an entry. For example, if a group has the attributes:

```
dn: cn=staff,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: posixGroup
description: The 'staff' group.
cn: staff
gidNumber: 50
memberUid: debianuser
memberUid: user1
uniqueMember: uid=user1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

And the entry `user1` has the attributes:

```
dn: uid=user1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: user1
cn: my-common-name
sn: my-surname
loginShell: /bin/bash
userPassword: {SSHA512}SCMmLlStPIxVtJc8Y6REiGTMsgSEFF7xVQFoYZYg39H0nEeDuK/fWxxNZ
 CdSYlRgJK3U3q0lYTka3Nre2CjXzeNUjbvHabYP
homeDirectory: /home/user1
uidNumber: 1002
gidNumber: 50
shadowLastChange: 15645
```

requesting the `memberOf` attribute yields the following:

```
ldapsearch -LLLh localhost -p 1389 -D cn=RootDN -w xxxxxx -b uid=user1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com -s base -l1 -z1 '(&)' memberOf
dn: uid=user1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
memberOf: cn=staff,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

The `memberOf` attribute is not a **physical** attribute, but rather a **virtual** attribute.

If an LDAP client cannot add an `objectClass` attribute to an entry, there are some possible reasons:

- the LDAP client's authorization state does not allow the client to modify the entry
- the LDAP client is attempting to add a second structural objectClass attribute to an entry. Multiple structural objectClasses are illegal, but some broken versions of the legacy Sun DSEE allowed it anyway.

Comment: the requesting command line doesn't work for me. The result is `version: 1, dn: uid=adminUser,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com`, no memberOf attribute there.

Comment: There is an operational attribute names `isMemberOf`.